# Generating a Pseudo-random sequence of plus/minus 1 integers

Tags: matlab, random, sequence, prng

Can anybody help me create a simple pseudo-random sequence of +-1 integers with length 1000 using Matlab?

I.e. a sequence such as

```
-1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1
```

I tried using this code below but this is the RANGE -1 to 1, which includes 0 values. I only want -1 and 1. Thanks

```
x = randi([-1 1],1000,1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try generating a random sequence of floating point numbers from `[0,1]` and any values less than 0.5 set to -1, and anything larger set to 1:

```
x = rand(1000,1);
ind = x >= 0.5;
x(ind) = 1;
x(~ind) = -1;
```

---

Another suggestion I have is to use the [`sign`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html) function combined with [`randn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) so that we can generate both positive and negative numbers.  `sign` generates values that are either -1, 0, 1 depending on the sign of the input. If the input is negative, the output is -1, +1 when positive and 0 when 0. You could do an additional check where any values that are output to 0, set them to -1 or 1:

```
x = sign(randn(1000,1));
x(x == 0) = 1;
```

---

One more (inspired by Luis Mendo) would be to have a vector of `[-1,1]` and use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to generate a sequence of either 1 or 2, then use this and sample into this vector:

```
vec = [-1 1];
x = vec(randi(numel(vec), 1000, 1));
```

This code can be extended where `vec` can be anything you want, and we can sample from any element in `vec` to produce a random sequence of values (observation made by Luis Mendo. Thanks!).

Comment: I like the samping approach using `randi` (+1 already), because it allows sampling a generic population

Comment: @LuisMendo - Thanks!  It's really based on `randsample`, but `randsample` requires the Stats toolbox... I figured I'd provide an alternative that doesn't require it.

Comment: @rayryeng For the sign(), randn almost surely never generates 0 so I'm sure that case can be ignored almost everywhere

Comment: @krisdestruction - I was thinking about that... but you never know.  I don't like small chances :P  There is that possibility!

Comment: @rayryeng I just ran this in Matlab `sum( rand( 10000000000, 1 ) == 0 )` and got `ans = 0`. That results in making an array that's ~762 Mb in size so I'm pretty sure there's no usable case that it will exactly equal zero. I'm sure you said that for completeness, and I'm just saying this for my completeness lol

Comment: @krisdestruction - .... there is still that possibility!  However, thanks for the computation verification though :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Third suggestion using vec is beautiful! :D

Answer (score 4):

Some alternatives:

```
x = 2*randi(2, 1000, 1)-3; %// generate 1 and 2 values, and transform to -1 and 1
x = 2*(rand(1, 1000, 1)<=.5)-1; %// similar to Rayryeng's answer but in one step
x = randsample([-1 1], 1000, true); %// sample with replacement from the set [-1 1]
```

Comment: @rayryeng Oops. I forgot "`<=.5`" with `rand`. Corrected now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply user **randsrc** function.

It will generate random sequences of 1 and -1.

For example

out = randsrc(2,3)

out =

```
-1    -1    -1
 1    -1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for these many helpful answers. I figure this topic might be general enough it may well deserve a comparison.

In my setup ( Windows8.4 x64 i74820k cpu and with R2014a) the fastest version is consistently:

```
x=2*round(rand(L,1))-1;
```

Being half an order of magnitude faster than the slowest solution. Hope this helps.

comparison: 
[figure comparing execution times for pseudo-random sign generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYniX.png)

code:

```
L=[];
for expon=0:6
    for mant=1:9
    L=cat(1,L,mant*power(10,expon));
    end
end
clear expon mant

t1=zeros(length(L),1);
x=2*round(rand(L(1),1))-1;
for li=1:length(L)
    tic,
    x=2*round(rand(L(li),1))-1;
    t1(li)=toc;
end

t2=zeros(length(L),1);
x=(rand(L(1),1)>0.5)*2-1;
for li=1:length(L)
    tic,
    x=(rand(L(li),1)>0.5)*2-1;
    t2(li)=toc;
end

t3=zeros(length(L),1);
x=(randi([0,1],L(1),1)>0.5)*2-1;
for li=1:length(L)
    tic,
    x=(randi([0,1],L(li),1)>0.5)*2-1;
    t3(li)=toc;
end

t4=zeros(length(L),1);
x=rand(L(1),1);ind=x>=0.5;x(ind)=1;x(~ind)=-1;
for li=1:length(L)
    tic,
    x=rand(L(li),1);
    ind=x>=0.5;
    x(ind)=1;
    x(~ind)=-1;
    t4(li)=toc;
end

t5=zeros(length(L),1);
x=sign(randn(L(1),1));
for li=1:length(L)
    tic,
    x=sign(randn(L(li),1));
    x(x==0)=1;
    t5(li)=toc;
end

t6=zeros(length(L),1);
vec = [-1 1];
x=vec(randi(numel(vec),L(1),1));
for li=1:length(L)
    tic,
    x=vec(randi(numel(vec),L(li),1));
    t6(li)=toc;
end

t7=zeros(length(L),1);
x=2*randi(2,L(1),1)-3;
for li=1:length(L)
    tic,
    x=2*randi(2,L(li),1)-3;
    t7(li)=toc;
end

t8=zeros(length(L),1);
x=randsample([-1 1],L(1),true);
for li=1:length(L)
    tic,
    x=randsample([-1 1],L(li),true);
    t8(li)=toc;
end

clear x vec ind li

figure,
loglog(L,[t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8],'.-','linewidth',2)
grid on 
grid minor
title('Generating pseudo-random sequence +1/-1')
ylabel('Exec. Time [s]')
xlabel('Output Vector Length')
T{1}='x=2*round(rand(L(1),1))-1';
T{2}='x=(rand(L(1),1)>0.5)*2-1';
T{3}='x=(randi([0,1],L(1),1)>0.5)*2-1';
T{4}='x=rand(L(1),1);ind=x>=0.5;x(ind)=1;x(~ind)=-1';
T{5}='x=sign(randn(L(1),1))';
T{6}='vec=[-1 1];x=vec(randi(numel(vec),L(1),1))';
T{7}='x=2*randi(2,L(1),1)-3';
T{8}='x=randsample([-1 1],L(1),true)';
legend(T,'location','northwest')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = rand(N,1);
y = sign(x-0.5);
```